# WSDL service reference with different urls for different users

Tags: web-services, reference, wsdl, visual-studio-2012

I have a WSDL service which I need to use in my project.

The URL of the webservice, the username and the password are different for each user.

I know how to add service reference. I do it with specific url. I give the url for the service to VS.

How do I do this when I want every user to have different url for the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically change the endpoint address.

See more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx) for WCF

Or for [legacy webservices](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/74179/Dynamically-Configure-Web-Service-Endpoint-for-Cli)